# css несколько фото

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Как при наведении на картинку активировать анимацию чтобы 1-3 сек одна фотка показывалась с эффектом постепенного появления, потом вторая 1-3 сек пс эффектом постепенного появления, затем третья 1 - 3 сек с эффектом постепенного появления. При этом пока курсор на картинке. Мой код:

```
#hat_logo_div {
     width : 20%;
     height: 4em;
      background-image: url(hat_logo2.png);
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код - это замечательно. Но вы сами пытались сделать то что вам нужно? Разместите код ваших попыток.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var iid;
  var imgSrc = ["https://i.posleurokov.ru/crop/300/300/events/3263/17a08bd84088547b073c99056c0764a3.jpg",
    "https://chitaem-skazki.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Сказки-А.-С.-Пушкина-300x300.jpg",
    "https://sochinyshka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Pushkin.jpg"
  ];
  var curImg = 0;
  $("#image").bind('mouseover', function() {
    iid = setInterval(function() {
      curImg < imgSrc.length - 1 ? ++curImg : curImg = 0;
      $("#image").attr("src", imgSrc[curImg]);
    }, 1000); //Время в секундах
  });
  $("#image").bind('mouseout', function() {
    clearInterval(iid);
    curImg = 0;
    this.src = imgSrc[0]
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Наведите на картинку</p>
<img id="image" src="https://i.posleurokov.ru/crop/300/300/events/3263/17a08bd84088547b073c99056c0764a3.jpg" />
```